# Use an image to fill a canvas object

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

Hey so I'm very new to this, and decided to learn by doing! And followed a tutorial to make a little jumping moving around game. Then I thought, wouldn't it be great to have the square be an image. So that's where my problems start. As I understand it the image I have fills the canvas in a repeat pattern, and when the square is over the top of it then you can see through to the image. And now I'm lost. Any tips on where to start fixing this or is it a lost cause?

```
const context = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
context.canvas.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;      //viewport height
context.canvas.width = Math.max(                                    //width of everything
  document.body.scrollWidth, document.documentElement.scrollWidth,
  document.body.offsetWidth, document.documentElement.offsetWidth,
  document.body.clientWidth, document.documentElement.clientWidth
);


// Create a collection to hold the generated x coordinates
const obXCoors = [];

const square = {    // size of the square
  height: 100,
  jumping: true,
  width: 100,
  x: 0,
  xVelocity: 0,
  y: 0,
  yVelocity: 0
};

const controller = {  
  left: false,
  right: false,
  up: false,
  keyListener: function (event) {
    var key_state = (event.type == "keydown") ? true : false;
    switch (event.keyCode) {
      case 37:// left key
        controller.left = key_state;
        break;
      case 32:// space key
        controller.jump = key_state;
        break;
      case 39:// right key
        controller.right = key_state;
        break;
    }
  }
};

const loop = function () {

  if (controller.jump && square.jumping == false) {
    square.yVelocity -= 50;
    square.jumping = true;
  }

  if (controller.left) {
    square.xVelocity -= 1;
  }

  if (controller.right) {
    square.xVelocity += 1;
  }

  square.yVelocity += 1.5;// gravity
  square.x += square.xVelocity;
  square.y += square.yVelocity;
  square.xVelocity *= 0.9;// friction
  square.yVelocity *= 0.9;// friction
  

  // if square is falling through the floor
  if (square.y > context.canvas.height - 100) {
    square.jumping = false;
    square.y = context.canvas.height - 100;
    square.yVelocity = 0;
  }

  // if square is going off the left of the screen
  if (square.x < -10) {
    square.x = 0;
  } 
  
  // if square goes past the right edge
  else if (square.x > context.canvas.width - 90) { 
    square.x = (context.canvas.width-100);
  }

  // scroll to the right
  var viewportwidth = window.innerWidth;
  if (square.x > (viewportwidth*0.8) + window.pageXOffset) {
    window.scrollBy(10,0);  
  }

  // scroll to the left
  else if (square.x < (viewportwidth * 0.2) + window.pageXOffset) {
    window.scrollBy(-10, 0);
  }

  // Creates the backdrop for each frame
  context.fillStyle = "white";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); // x, y, width, height

  const run = document.createElement("IMG");
  run.setAttribute("src", "img/run.gif");
  run.setAttribute("width", "100");
  run.setAttribute("height", "100");
  run.setAttribute("alt", "run");
  
  const pattern = context.createPattern(run,'repeat');

  // Creates and fills the cube for each frame
  context.fillStyle = pattern; // hex for cube color
  context.beginPath();
  context.rect(square.x, square.y, square.width, square.height);
  context.fill();


  // call update when the browser is ready to draw again
  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop); 
};


window.addEventListener("keydown", controller.keyListener)
window.addEventListener("keyup", controller.keyListener);
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  // space and arrow keys
  if([32, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}, false);
window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const context = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
context.canvas.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;      //viewport height
context.canvas.width = Math.max(                                    //width of everything
  document.body.scrollWidth, document.documentElement.scrollWidth,
  document.body.offsetWidth, document.documentElement.offsetWidth,
  document.body.clientWidth, document.documentElement.clientWidth
);


// Create a collection to hold the generated x coordinates
const obXCoors = [];

const square = {    // size of the square
  height: 100,
  jumping: true,
  width: 100,
  x: 0,
  xVelocity: 0,
  y: 0,
  yVelocity: 0
};

const controller = {  
  left: false,
  right: false,
  jump: false,
  keyListener: function (event) {
    var key_state = (event.type == "keydown") ? true : false;
    switch (event.keyCode) {
      case 37:// left key
        controller.left = key_state;
        break;
      case 32:// space key
        controller.jump = key_state;
        break;
      case 39:// right key
        controller.right = key_state;
        break;
    }
  }
};

const loop = function () {

  if (controller.jump && square.jumping == false) {
    square.yVelocity -= 50;
    square.jumping = true;
  }

  if (controller.left) {
    square.xVelocity -= 1;
  }

  if (controller.right) {
    square.xVelocity += 1;
  }

  square.yVelocity += 1.5;// gravity
  square.x += square.xVelocity;
  square.y += square.yVelocity;
  square.xVelocity *= 0.9;// friction
  square.yVelocity *= 0.9;// friction
  

  // if square is falling through the floor
  if (square.y > context.canvas.height - 100) {
    square.jumping = false;
    square.y = context.canvas.height - 100;
    square.yVelocity = 0;
  }

  // if square is going off the left of the screen
  if (square.x < -10) {
    square.x = 0;
  } 
  
  // if square goes past the right edge
  else if (square.x > context.canvas.width - 90) { 
    square.x = (context.canvas.width-100);
  }

  // scroll to the right
  var viewportwidth = window.innerWidth;
  if (square.x > (viewportwidth*0.8) + window.pageXOffset) {
    window.scrollBy(10,0);  
  }

  // scroll to the left
  else if (square.x < (viewportwidth * 0.2) + window.pageXOffset) {
    window.scrollBy(-10, 0);
  }
   
  // Creates the backdrop for each frame
  context.fillStyle = "#FFF";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); // x, y, width, height

  // Creates and fills the cube for each frame
  context.beginPath();
  base_image = new Image();
  base_image.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,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';
  context.drawImage(base_image, square.x, square.y);


  // call update when the browser is ready to draw again
  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop); 
};


window.addEventListener("keydown", controller.keyListener)
window.addEventListener("keyup", controller.keyListener);
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  // space and arrow keys
  if([32, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}, false);
window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

The code created the image like this:

```
  const run = document.createElement("IMG");
  run.setAttribute("src", "img/run.gif");
  run.setAttribute("width", "100");
  run.setAttribute("height", "100");
  run.setAttribute("alt", "run");
  
  const pattern = context.createPattern(run,'repeat');
  context.fillStyle = pattern; // hex for cube color
  context.beginPath();
  context.rect(square.x, square.y, square.width, square.height);
  context.fill();
```

I have replaced it with

```
  base_image = new Image();
  base_image.src = 'img/run.gif';
  context.drawImage(base_image, square.x, square.y);
```

I also fixed a typo in:

```
const controller = {  
  left: false,
  right: false,
  up: false, // should be 'jump' not 'up'
```

Comment: It works perfectly thank you! I've never seen anything about base image before I'll have a read about it.  Thankssssss again.